# jquery extensions and webpack

Tags: jquery, webpack

I'm trying to add some jQuery plugins (like slim-scroll or jquery-ui) to webpack managed project. But get an error

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: $(...).slimScroll is not a function
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: How are you adding them at the moment?

Comment: @destination-data, I've added jquery through plugins

`new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    })`
and then tried to resolve extensions through alias:
`$.slimScroll: path.resolve("jquery-slimscroll")`

Comment: @SerogaMell, ever figure this out?